# simple Array Sort by JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Ignore my poor English, just a little code

may be you can find something not poor

```
let arr = [10, 5, 4, 22, 0, 25, 1000, 1, 5555 , 5464564]; //example Array
let j = 0; //tag
let m = 0; //count
for(var i = 0; i <= arr.length-1; i++){
    m++;
    console.log(i);
    if(arr[i] > arr[i + 1]){
        [arr[i], arr[i + 1]] = [arr[i + 1], arr[i]]; //exchange
        j = Math.max(i, j);
        i = Math.max(i - 2, -1); 
    }
    else {
        if(i < j){
            i = Math.max(i, j); // get tag
        }
    }
}
console.log(arr, j, m); //result tag count
```

I find it always compare more times than I design when  `i = 0` , how can I resolve it

Comment: Could you please describe what exactly the problem with your code is?

Comment: I want try it by myself, the trouble is it run more times  when i = 0 ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I couldn't find why it did it, but tried your code by removing `j` and I understand now :p

## test without `j`

here we can see that whenever `i` enconter a pair needing to be swapped it come back to `i - 2`

if `i` equal `0` two times it is because after swapping the pair `arr[0]` - `arr[1]` it look again at this pair to be sure it was corretly swapped

```js
arr = [10, 5, 4, 22, 0, 25, 1000, 1,5555 ,5464564];
let m = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    m++;
    console.log(i);
    // let's log the array as well
    console.log(arr);
    if(arr[i] > arr[i + 1]){
        [arr[i], arr[i + 1]] = [arr[i + 1], arr[i]];
        
        // j = Math.max(i, j);
        i = Math.max(i - 2, -1); 
    }
    else {
        // if(i < j){
        //     i = Math.max(i, j);
        // }
    }
}

console.log(arr, m);
```

## let's re-add `j`

by adding `j` back we can see that it serve as "checkpoint" for `i`, the same behavior as before explain why `i === 0`

```js
let arr = [10, 5, 4, 22, 0, 25, 1000, 1, 5555 , 5464564];
let j = 0;
let m = 0;

for(var i = 0; i <= arr.length-1; i++){
    m++;
    console.log(i);
    console.log(arr);
    if(arr[i] > arr[i + 1]){
        [arr[i], arr[i + 1]] = [arr[i + 1], arr[i]]; //exchange
        j = Math.max(i, j);
        i = Math.max(i - 2, -1); 
    }
    else {
        if(i < j){
            i = Math.max(i, j); // get tag
        }
    }
}
console.log(arr, j, m); //result tag count
```

## finally a solution

since we found `i` is still at `0` to ensure it swapped them **BUT** we know they are swapped so `i` doesn't need to stay `0` so how about removing this useless security?

```js
let arr = [10, 5, 4, 22, 0, 25, 1000, 1, 5555 , 5464564];
let j = 0;
let m = 0;

for(var i = 0; i <= arr.length-1; i++){
    m++;
    console.log(i);
    console.log(arr);
    if(arr[i] > arr[i + 1]){
        [arr[i], arr[i + 1]] = [arr[i + 1], arr[i]];
        j = Math.max(i, j);
        
        // Here
        if (i !== 0) {
           i = Math.max(i - 2, -1); 
        }
        
    }
    else {
        if(i < j){
            i = Math.max(i, j);
        }
    }
}
console.log(arr, j, m);
```

---

if you don't have/really want to do it yourself use [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
let arr = [10, 5, 4, 22, 0, 25, 1000, 1,5555 ,5464564];
// the parseInt are needed because javascript will try to cast your values to string
console.log(arr.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a) - parseInt(b)))
```

Comment: Thank you ,I know  the sort of Array how to work in JS.

Comment: Now the trouble is the funciton run more times when i = 0 ;

Comment: @James looking into it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind checking this: `for(var i=0; **i<=arr.length-1**; i++)`? Specifically the `<=` sign

Comment: `i <= arr.length - 1` is the same as `i < arr.length`.  Since the loop uses `arr[i + 1]` it could cause an error when `i == arr.length - 1`